# Building a document management system

Tags: php, mysql, architecture, scalability

A client wants a web based document management system for their firm, which consists of various departments.
I have never built anything like this before, so am a little lost on where to begin.
I intend to build it using php,mysql with codeiginter
Their requirements include

- web interface
- mainly office docs; word,pdf,text
- mutliple user access to documents
- versioning
- check-ins and outs

I will appreciate any information pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Why don't you try using Google Apps for Domains, which gives you a branded one on your company's name? Still do you wish to create on your own?

Comment: there are many open source options as well.

Comment: Sorry, this question is a little too broad and too specific to your situation for SO. Sounds more like you need a project manager than a Q&A site.

Comment: Also if you wish to use some Open Source ones, I strongly recommend [FengOffice](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/)

Comment: @PraveenKumar i'll have to ask the client if they dont mind using google apps for domains, but i would like to create my own for learning process et all

Comment: @PraveenKumar i will look into open source options

Comment: @MrFoh Check out FengOffice! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a little knowledge about how to build the software but I know about the software which will fulfill all the needs of your client.
In the market, there are a lot more software providers like project management, Billing software, invoice software, accounting software etc.

According to the needs of your client, "Document management system software" would be the most suitable of all.

1. web interface
2. List item
3. mainly office docs; word,pdf,text
4. mutliple user access to documents versioning
5. check-ins and outs

**Web Interface**

Document management system is the online tool in which you can access the software with the internet or with the web interface. Another benefit of the document management system is that you can log in to the software from different locations and check the on-going, completed and pending tasks

**List item**

You can easily list the items of your products or services in a line-up format. Also, you can list up the on-going and completed tasks

**Mainly Office Docs, Word,PDF,Text**

All the documents in DMS software are in MS office formats like word, PDF, PTP & text format ( According to the demand of your Client)

**Multi Users Login Access**

In DMS system you can easily create multiple user logins with the limited access

**Check in & Outs**

Check-ins and Check-outs are not the part of DMS system but you can add up these things in the software.

**If you are interested in getting the software you can get the Laserfiche Document Management system**